# Discord.js outputting an entire array but want to add an emoji to correspond with each object

Tags: discord.js

I am writing Guild Wars 2 commands into my bot and I have a wallet command which looks up ID's against an endpoint to give each ID a name. What I would like to do is instead of just displaying the name, I would like to display an emoji of each thing. For example, karma symbol for karma, gem symbol for gems. Adding emojis is easy, I get that part, however I can't wrap my head around how to identify what each line in the output is going to be as it is different per account that is looked up.

Here is my code so far:

```
 var newArray = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < walletArray.length; i++) {
     for (var x = 0; x < currencyArray.length; x++) {
         if (walletArray[i].id === currencyArray[x].id) {
             if (currencyArray[x].name === "Coin") {
                 var bronze = String(walletArray[i].value).slice(-2)
                 var silver = String(walletArray[i].value).slice(-4, -2)
                 var gold = String(walletArray[i].value).slice(0, -4)
             }
             newArray.push(`${currencyArray[x].name} - ${walletArray[i].value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")}`)
         }
     }
}
```

The walletArray (or part of it) is:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "value": 57636
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "value": 32969
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "value": 36
    }
]
```

The `currencyArray` is:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Coin",
    "description": "The primary currency of Tyria. Spent at vendors throughout the world.",
    "order": 101,
    "icon": "https://render.guildwars2.com/file/98457F504BA2FAC8457F532C4B30EDC23929ACF9/619316.png"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Karma",
    "description": "Earned through various activities. Spent at vendors throughout the world.",
    "order": 102,
    "icon": "https://render.guildwars2.com/file/94953FA23D3E0D23559624015DFEA4CFAA07F0E5/155026.png"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Laurel",
    "description": "Earned through the Log-in Reward Chest. Spent in major cities. Used to purchase various rewards.",
    "order": 104,
    "icon": "https://render.guildwars2.com/file/A1BD345AD9192C3A585BE2F6CB0617C5A797A1E2/619317.png"
}
```

The output is:
[Wallet command output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwsE5.png)

I have no idea if I am even approaching this correctly but I just want it to look a bit nicer! It is fully functional just we can always improve things. My JS is not the best, it was learned during lockdown as something to do and was learned almost entirely from this website!

Any help would be appreciated, cheers.

Comment: You should probably post some sample value of both `walletArray` and `currencyArray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if I understand your problem correctly, you *know* each line of the output is gonna be, because of `currencyArray.name`. The solution should be something like:

```
var newArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < walletArray.length; i++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < currencyArray.length; x++) {
        if (walletArray[i].id === currencyArray[x].id) {
            var emote;
            if (currencyArray[x].name === "Coin") {
                emote = ""
                var bronze = String(walletArray[i].value).slice(-2)
                var silver = String(walletArray[i].value).slice(-4, -2)
                var gold = String(walletArray[i].value).slice(0, -4)
            }
            else if (currencyArray[x].name === "Karma") {
                emote = "☯️"
            }
            else if (currencyArray[x].name === "Laurel") {
                emote = ""
            }
            newArray.push(`${emote} ${currencyArray[x].name} - ${walletArray[i].value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")}`)
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, use any emotes you wish.

Comment: Thank you KifoPL, of course it was a simple solution in the end that I couldn't find for ages! Even though I have done a very similar thing many times before. Resolving arrays against each other though is very new to me!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). discord.js names it `Collection` but they are pretty much the same.

```js
let myMap = new Map();
myMap.set('key', 'emoji')
let emoji1 = myMap.get('key') //'emoji'
```

The 'key' is linked to the value which you can get with the `Map.get` method